# Docker Dynamic environment variable in ECS Task Definition container json

Tags: json, docker, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

Currently we are working on a migration resilient project where we choose AWS ECS as a container orchestration choice. Here we got a interesting problem where we are trying to get a unique value for a specific environment variable whenever a new container is spins.

Below command creates a unique value each time a new container spins.

```
docker run --env SERVICE_TAG=$(uuidgen) yourimage
```

But when we are trying to define the same in container definition json. The value is getting taken as string.

We tried below things

```
{
  "name": "SERVICE_TAG",
  "value": "${`uidgen`}"
}


{
  "name": "SERVICE_TAG",
  "value": "${`uidgen`}"
}


{
  "name": "SERVICE_TAG",
  "value": "${`uidgen`}"
}


{
  "name": "SERVICE_TAG",
  "value": "${uidgen}"
}

{
  "name": "SERVICE_TAG",
  "value": "uidgen"
}
```

But nothing worked. Everything is turning into string, with out double quotes the pattern is not getting accepted as it is not a valid json.

Can someone please help on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `overrides` option to change your environment variable. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html